# How to determine which panel holds a button that was pressed - Application Window

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I have an array of Tile objects (Panel, Button to a tile) in a JPanel, 20x20. If button 1 is clicked, a thing happens, button 2 is pressed, a thing happens, etc.

I want a specific function to happen every time a button other than one in the top row is clicked (the top row of buttons all have functions assigned, the other 380 buttons do not have assigned functions).

So in the top buttons' cases I have the code:

```
if(e.getSource() == tiles[0][0].button)
    {
    //do stuff
    }
else if(e.getSource() == tiles[0][1].button)
    {
    //do stuff
    }
```

For the other buttons, I want something along the lines of:

```
JButton button;
button = e.getSource();
JPanel hostPanel = button.PanelInWhichButtonisContained();
```

but I'm not sure what the syntax or what sort I would to do achieve that task. I don't really have any code to present prior attempts because I'm not sure how to approach this task, but I haven't been able to find anything on the World Wide Web to help me in this task.

I'm currently just using default application window libraries and classes (javax.swing, java.awt, etc) but I'm completely open to downloading external libraries.

Comment: What do you mean by _all have functions assigned_?  Each button in the first row could have its own listener instance so that large if/else could be avoided.  The other buttons could share a listener and for example use `event.getSource().getParent(),dispatchEvent()`, and the JPanel that needs to do something will get the event (if the JPanel has a registered listener.)

Comment: @AndrewS In all honestly, I kind of brushed over the top row of buttons (I was just trying to explain what the point of this is, e.g. a set of buttons that have functions assigned to them). I actually updated them to... err, I think the term is 'anonymous functions'? shortly after I posted my question. .getParent() seems to be the method I was looking for, thanks. ~~I'll update if that solves my problem.~~ That does in fact solve my problem, thanks. If you want to post your answer as a top-level, go ahead - otherwise I'll answer it myself later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determining the "source" of an action like a button press in the `actionPerformed` method is usually brittle (and fortunately, hardly ever necessary).

This means that this is **highly** questionable:

```
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // DON'T DO THIS!
        if (e.getSource() == someButton) doThis();
        if (e.getSource() == someOtherButton) doThad();
    }
}
```

You should usually **NOT** do this.

And of course, it's even worse to add casts and walk up some container hierarchy:

```
// DON'T DO THIS!
Object source = e.getSource();
Component button = (Component)source;
Component parent = button.getParent();
if (parent == somePanel) doThis();
if (parent == someOtherPanel) doThat();
```

---

In basically all cases, it is far more flexible and elegant to attach a listener to the button that is *specific* for the button - meaning that it **knows** what the button should do.

For individual buttons, this can be solved the old-fashioned way, using an anonymous inner class:

```
class Gui {

    void create() {
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                startSomething();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startSomething() { ... }
}
```

The same can be written far more concisely using lambda expressions with Java 8:

```
class Gui {

    void create() {
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(e -> startSomething());
    }

    private void startSomething() { ... }
}
```

(A side note: I consider it as a good practice to only call a single method in the `ActionListener` implementation anyhow. The `actionPerformed` method should not contain many lines of code, and particularly no "business logic". There should be a dedicated method for *what the button does* - for example, to `startSomething`, as in the example above)

---

For buttons that are contained in arrays, as in the example in your question, there is a neat trick to retain the information about the button that was clicked:

```
class Gui {

    JButton buttons[];

    void create() {

        buttons = new JButton[5];
        for (int i=0; j<buttons.length; i++) { 
            int index = i;
            buttons[i] = new JButton("Button " + i);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(e -> clickedButton(index));
        }
    }

    private void clickedButton(int index) { 
        System.out.println("Clicked button at index " + index);
    }
}
```

In many cases, you then don't even have to keep the `JButton buttons[]` array any more. Often you can just create the buttons, add them to some panel, and then are only interested in the `index` that is passed to the `clickedButton` method. (The `button[]` array may be necessary in some cases, though - for example, if you want to change the label of a button after it was clicked).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response! This has, in addition to earlier comments, mostly solved my issues.

For some greater context (largely irrelevant to original question), a friend of mine and I are working on a dinky little game for a high school computer science project. It's essentially roguelite fire emblem, and we have a Character() object assigned to each tile in the array. By finding the source of the button, we can interact with the character object which is part of the button. We've figured out a way to work past that through some.. questionable enum-like behavior...

Comment: However, we're not being graded too heavily on proper code quality and just achieving functionality, but we're doing our best to keep things smooth.

I think the array is necessary for what we're doing, though - e.x. if tile 4,5 is clicked, turn tile 2,3 red seems to be most simply solved with an array of Tile objects. If that's not the case, I'm obviously open to correction, but I haven't found a better one :)

Comment: @EliK One could talk very broadly about different aspects of "software design". From what you described, there should/could probably some sort of "Game Model" - a representation of *the game itself* that is largely unaware of the UI. (Basically in the sense of [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) ). So there *will* be some form of "array" for representing the board, but in a "clean design", this array should not contain *buttons*, but only the (UI-agnostic) game elements. Describing this is beyond the scope of a comment or answer here, though.